# Simple Ember Route not working?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Not sure why I can't get the edit page to display... This is as barebones as it gets?

I have:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){

  this.route('bank-account.edit', { path: '/bank-account/edit' });
});
```

And templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>App</h1>

  {{#link-to 'bank-account.edit'}}Bank account edit{{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bank-account.edit">
  <h3>Edit</h3>
  Where am I??
  </script>
```

Here's the jsbin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cetaxe/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

periods need to be converted to `/` in the template names

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bank-account/edit">
  <h3>Edit</h3>
  Where am I??
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dagekazo/1/edit